# anyone please explain relationship between MS office and VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Please explain the relationship between MS office and VBA Macros .I tried it to search on google but never found an perfect answer.

Comment: What are the results of your research? Maybe it would help to explain what you have learned so far. E.g. as far as I can see the [VBA Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) entry is very informative. It's better to ask specific questions for the parts which are not clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA or Visual Basic for Applications is a small scripting language which can be used in Microsoft applications to automate tasks, extend functionality and more.

Each host application e.g. Word, Excel provides a set of APIs to VBA which the programmer can make use of to interact with said host application and the open document. These programs are typically referred to as macros.

A macro is a small snippet of this VBA code which has been created and stored within a document or file for a host application. This macro can take inputs as well as interact with the user through GUI components and then make changes to a document. Hotkeys can be assigned to launch macros for convenience as well as menus, buttons and events.

Macros can be harmful if run from an untrusted third party source. For more information regarding security concerns [read this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/171993/macros-explained-why-microsoft-office-files-can-be-dangerous/).